# Скрипт изменения цвета

Tags: javascript, скрипт

В общем то есть сайт,и с ним проблема..на сайте есть множество всплывающих окон, вагон и маленькая тележка, цвет фона всех этих элементов - #4b4b4b.
А дело то в том,что цвета на сайте все белых оттенков, основные элементы красные..есть ли скрипт которым можно на всем сайте заменить цвет #4b4b4b на #f3f3f3?

Comment: А цвет фона к чему привязан? Есть же класс с этим цветом? Почему бы прямо в CSS не изменть его background-color?) P.s. скриптом-то можно.

Comment: Нет полного доступа к стилям,и шаблонам этих всплывающих окон..тут только перебить можно

Comment: Можно пробовать для начала `.класс-окна { background-color: #f3f3f3 !important; }` — если у них в стилях тоже нет important, перебьет.

Comment: Это не подойдёт, пробовал..Тут наверное только то что в описании вопроса подойдёт..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбираете все нужные элементы селекторами и в css задаете стиль **самом конце**, переопределяя его.

```css
/*Конец файла*/
.items {
    color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

---

JavaScript'ом можно сделать вот так (тоже подключить в **самый конец**):

```js
items = document.querySelectorAll('.class');

items.forEach(function(i){
    i.style.color = '#f3f3f3';
});
```

Если много разных классов, то использовать селектор по цвету:

```js
items = document.querySelectorAll('.class[style="color: #f3f3f3"]');

items.forEach(function(i){
    i.style.color = '#f3f3f3';
});
```

Если нужны только выборочные элементы и их тоже много, то только ручками, или у них нет атрибута style.

Comment: Ну а как можно именно цвет #4b4b4b заменить на #f3f3f3.Дело то в том что для каждого элемента свой класс,их очень и очень много

Comment: Если их очень и очень много, тогда нужно было уже заранее придумывать структуру классов и придумали бы класс `.-c-light-yellow {color: #f3f3f3}` и задавали бы элементу, которому это надо было бы, а потом при надобности бы поменяли в один миг. Но увы, раз структура непродуманна заранее, то только ручками все исправлять - вот вам и рефакторинг :), если вообще лень то можете придумать ИИ который за вас сайты будет писать в одну кнопочку, считывая мысли. Вот чем грозит плохо продуманная архитектура - мешает развитию и внедрению новых элементов, а так же исправлений.

Comment: @Mully P.s. спасибо, проверил свой вариант на 100.000 элементах... больше не хочу!))

Answer (score -1):

Допустим у нас модальные окна с классом `modal`. У Вас нет полного доступа к стилям, но доступы всё же есть! создайте класс `active` и добавляйте его на все модальные окна. В данном классе указываёте Ваш цвет (в коде ниже красится в красный для лучшего обзора )

Если у каждого модального окна разный класс и нет вообще ничего общего!мтогда придётся писать код вроде того который ниже для каждого элемента. Как правило, у окон всплывающих должны быть разные id, а классы определяющие что это всплывающие окна могут повторяться для задания тех же общих цветов фона! Лучше скиньте примерную структуру шаблона, уверен у них есть какой-либо общий класс!

```js
var modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
modal.forEach(function(item) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    item.classList.add('active')
  }, 400);
});
```

```css
.modal {
  background-color: #4b4b4b;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

body {
  background: white;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.active {
  background-color: red !important/*#f3f3f3*/;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="modal"></div>
  <div class="modal"></div>
  <div class="modal"></div>
  <div class="modal"></div>
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Речь идет не о модалках и как их тогглить)